# Magento module works on OS X not Linux

Tags: linux, macos, magento, case-sensitive

I'm having problems getting my magento module working on linux.
It works without any problems on os x.

This is the structure of my module

```
app
├── code
│   └── local
│       └── Vuuh
│           └── ProductFeed
│               ├── Block
│               │   ├── Adminhtml
│               │   │   └── ProductFeed.php
│               │   └── Index.php
│               ├── controllers
│               │   ├── Adminhtml
│               │   │   └── AdminController.php
│               │   └── ProductController.php
│               ├── etc
│               │   ├── adminhtml.xml
│               │   └── config.xml
│               ├── Helper
│               │   └── Data.php
│               ├── Model
│               │   ├── Resource
│               │   │   ├── ProductFeed
│               │   │   │   └── Collection.php
│               │   │   └── ProductFeed.php
│               │   └── ProductFeed.php
│               │
│               └── sql
│                   └── vuuh_productfeed_setup
│                       └── install-0.0.1.php
├── design
│    └── adminhtml
│        └── default
│            └── default
│                ├── layout
│                │   └── productfeed.xml
│                └── template
│                    └── productfeed
│                        └── productfeed.phtml
└── etc
    └── modules
        └── Vuuh_ProductFeed.xml
```

This is my `config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>

<!-- Module -->
<modules>
    <Vuuh_ProductFeed>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </Vuuh_ProductFeed>
</modules>

<!-- Frontend -->
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <vuuh_productfeed>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Vuuh_ProductFeed</module>
                <frontName>vuuhproductfeed</frontName>
            </args>
        </vuuh_productfeed>
    </routers>
</frontend>

<!-- Admin-->
<admin>
    <routers>
        <Vuuh_ProductFeed>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Vuuh_ProductFeed</module>
                <frontName>productfeed</frontName>
            </args>
        </Vuuh_ProductFeed>
    </routers>
</admin>

<!-- Adminhtml -->
<adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <productfeed>
                <file>productfeed.xml</file>
            </productfeed>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml>

<!-- Global -->
<global>
    <models>
        <vuuh_productfeed>
            <class>Vuuh_ProductFeed_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>vuuh_productfeed_resource</resourceModel>
        </vuuh_productfeed>

        <vuuh_productfeed_resource>
            <class>Vuuh_ProductFeed_Model_Resource</class>
            <entities>
                <productfeed>
                    <table>vuuh_productfeed_productfeed</table>
                </productfeed>
            </entities>
        </vuuh_productfeed_resource>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <vuuh_productfeed_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Vuuh_ProductFeed</module>
                <class>Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </vuuh_productfeed_setup>
    </resources>
    <helpers>
        <productfeed>
            <class>Vuuh_ProductFeed_Helper</class>
        </productfeed>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
        <productfeed>
            <class>Vuuh_ProductFeed_Block</class>
        </productfeed>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

I have researched a bit and found out that the issue may be because of case sensivity on Linux. But i can't find any errors in my config?

Mage::getModel("vuuh_productfeed/productfeed") does not find the class.

```
$productfeed = Mage::getModel("vuuh_productfeed/productfeed")->getCollection();

Fatal error: Call to a member function getCollection() on a non-object in /var/www/magento18/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/productfeed/productfeed.phtml
```

I have stared at that config for hours now. I cannot find the error.
The module loads fine. It is just that one class that will not load.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is case sensitivity. 
File names on windows are not case sensitive. On UNIX they are.
So when calling `Mage::getModel("vuuh_productfeed/productfeed")` Magento looks for the file

`Vuuh/ProductFeed/Model/Productfeed.php` but your file name is
`Vuuh/ProductFeed/Model/ProductFeed.php`

You have 2 options here.
Either change all your calls for `getModel` (and createBlock and other factories) to for example

```
Mage::getModel("vuuh_productfeed/productFeed")
```

But this approach is kind of time consuming.

The second option is to rename your files from `ProductFeed.php` to `Productfeed.php`. You can also change the class names inside those files, but that's not mandatory because class names are note case sensitive in PHP. But just to be "politically correct" you should change them.

Comment: I fixed it by renaming the model file :) Thank you!

Comment: @Razcou Don't forget you have 3 such files. One model, one resource model and one block.